# Where is texture mapping panel in 2.8?

Tags: texturing, uv, interface

I can not find Texture channel panel (image below) in 2.8

[image]

The picture was on blender manual.

Comment: Blender Internal is no longer included in Blender 2.8x. You will have to use the *Texture Coordinate* and *Mapping* node to accomplish the same task for Cycles and Eevee.

Answer (score 2):

The Blender Internal (BI) render engine is no longer a part of Blender since the 2.80 release, which means that this specific panel no longer exists. However Cycles and Eevee both have a node-based material system that lets you configure the same properties. Switch to the *Shading* [workspace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/workspaces.html) *or* open the [*Shader Editor*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor/index.html) in one of the areas.

[image: Workspace]
<sub>Shading Workspace</sub>

[image]
<sub>Shader Editor</sub>

The basic node setup uses a *Texture Coordinate*, 
*Mapping* and *Image Texture* node.

[image: Nodes]

The [*Texture Coordinate*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html) node provides access to the active UV map, which can be used as input to the [*Mapping*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/mapping.html) node. Similar to the texture panel for Blender Internal, you can adjust the location (BI: *Offset*) and scale (BI: *Size*) as well as the rotation. The vector output of the mapping node is connected to the [*Image Texture*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html) node. There you can find the *Projection* property.

The [*UV Map*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/uv_map.html) node is useful if you want to use a specific UV map, not just the currently active one. In this case you can replace the *Texture Coordinate* node with it.

All nodes offer even more options, that are documented in the linked pages of Blender's manual.