# My face texture won't work, the body is fine

Tags: texturing, materials

[image: 1]

So i have the head as a separate piece right, but still the same model and no matter what i do, i can't get a texture on the face. A little help please, i have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: May have put this in the wrong section sorry

Comment: Can you show the node setup for your material? It looks like you haven't connected any texture to the base color of the *Principled BSDF*.

Comment: question how would i get to the "Node Setup" im very new to blender

Comment: ok i found the node thing what now (Its Blank)

Comment: Go to the Shading workspace, select the head, make sure that *Use Nodes* is enabled. Create the texture setup like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165212/where-is-texture-mapping-panel-in-2-8) and connect it to the base color of the Principled BSDF..